# Does the BackgroundWorker provide real multithreading?

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

Learning to build multithreading WPF applications I read about some restrictions in using BackgroundWorker that was not very clear for me. Please, help me to understand:

If I want not only one thread working behind the scene of UI, but maybe several ones, starting and ending independently one from another, will the BackgroundWorker fit in such a case? Can I have multiple instances of the BackgroundWorker?

Simply put, does the BackgroundWorker provide a multithreading and not simply a two-threading?

Comment: Do you have a link to the restrictions that you read about?

Comment: @Mark Byers  For example this paragraph (from "Pro WPF in C# 2008" book by Matthew MacDonald):
"Note: The BackgroundWorker is perfect if you have a single asynchronous task that runs in the background from start to finish (with optional support for progress reporting and cancellation). If you have something else in mind—for example, an asynchronous task that runs throughout the entire life of your application or an asynchronous task that communicates with your application while it does its work, you’ll need to design a customized solution using .NET’s threading support."

Comment: I think it's more a question of what is regarded as good design than of what is technically possible. You *can* create many BackgroundWorkers, but it might not be the best way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each `BackgroundWorker` runs a on a separate thread. You can create as many background workers as you need to run operations in parallel, so in that sense it is true multithreading.

The benefit of `BackgroundWorker` is the ease with which you can subscribe events that will fire on your UI thread when the time-consuming task completes.

Using `BackgroundWorker` is actually quite simple:

```
var worker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
worker1.DoWork += (sender,e) => Thread.Sleep(10000);
worker1.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender,e) => MessageBox.Show("Worker1 Finished!");
worker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

The restrictions you quote (from Pro WPF) stem from the fact that a BGW uses the ThreadPool so all [rules and adivice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx) regarding ThreadPool threads do apply.

Comment: Thanks for a useful info and link +1

Answer (score 2):

If you create many `BackgroundWorker` instances then you get many threads, a single instance provides for only a single background task however.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, internally, the Background worker calls BeginInvoke on you're provided delegate. This will result in your delegate being placed on a thread pool in the CLR.